# How to access columns in DetailView?

Tags: c#, devexpress, master-detail, xtragrid

I am using Master-detail view, with all grid data read from DataSource BindingList (So I can't set column settings in Designer).

The grid has DateTime columns that show only Date by default, which I want to change to show both Date and Time.

I am able to set this for columns in main/master view by

```
foreach (GridColumn column in gridView.Columns)
   if (column.ColumnType == typeof(DateTime))
      column.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "g";
```

But I cannot access the DetailView columns. I tried using method gridView.GetDetailView, but that only returns BaseView, which doesn't have Columns property. I also checked some events like gridView.CustomColumnDisplayText, but that didn't fire on detail views.

How can I programmatically access the columns of a Detail View?
Or even better, how to set default format for DateTime columns in the whole Master-detail grid?

Answer (score 2):

Probably figured it out after all, the point is BaseView can be cast to GridView, then I can access GridColumns as usual.